# GSM AT command to disable ring report

Tags: gsm, at-command, sms-gateway

I'm developing a sms application using a Portech MT-350 GSM gateway.
This box automatically sends to client a report when a call is incoming.
Something like:

```
+CLIP "0123456789"....,2
```

I could remove the CLIP informations with `AT+CLIP=0` command but it still send a single status digit:

```
2 for ring
3 for call closed.
```

I need to disable all this codes, I don't want any unsollicited message by the box because it dirties the TE-TA comunication during sms sending.
I tried also the `AT+CNMI=0,0,0,0,0` command without success.

Can you suggest something to try?  I can not understand if this is a standard behaviour of a GSM TE or if it is particular of this box.

Answer (score 0):

As I remember, `AT+GSMBUSY=1` rejects all incoming calls. Not a perfect decision, but maybe it helps.